# cannot interact with WebElements in Chrome browser (version 67.0.3396.87) with latest version of Selenium 3.12

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to log in to a webpage and want to pass userId and password .It's not passing the userid/ password and page is stalled.Getting following exception-

"{The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:6905/session/4e1158e787cbb6d6a16e5352a290cc89/element/0.5806346454853202-1/click timed out after 60 seconds."}"
  Using chromedriver version 2.40.0 , Chrome Browser version is  67.0.3396.87 and Selenium webdriver version is 3.12

Also noticed the same issue with IE11 .
Please provide any help/suggestion regarding this .

```
IWebDriver IeDriver;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
            options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
IeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
IeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://in.linkedin.com/");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
IeDriver.FindElement(By.Id("login-email")).Click();
```

Exception is thrown from Click() method.
"{The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:6905/session/4e1158e787cbb6d6a16e5352a290cc89/element/0.5806346454853202-1/click timed out after 60 seconds."}"

StackTrace :
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:6109/session/8d807d90c1f7f6d35b8ac3bbf9bf91c1/element/0.6394445294841895-2/click timed out after 60 seconds.
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
   at TestSelenium.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\arunangshuj884\source\repos\TestSelenium\TestSelenium\Program.cs:line 76

Inner Exception 1:
WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

Comment: Update your chromedriver nuget package.

Comment: I have the latest chromedriver 2.4 . Still getting the issue

Comment: Version 2.4 of chromedriver.exe is ancient; don’t confuse it with 2.40.

Comment: yes I am using 2.40.0 Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver along with 3.12.0 version of Selenium.WebDriver .Still looking for a possible solution and trying to find out If I am missing something!!

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Comment: Added the Stacktrace in question